# Mapping flows onto each other

Tags: calculus, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $T=\mathbb{R}$ or $T=\mathbb{Z}$. We assume we are given two continuous flows
$$\Phi_1: T \times M \rightarrow M$$
and
$$\Phi_2: T \times M \rightarrow M$$
Let's further assume we can choose two continuous functions $h,h'$.

**My question is the following:** Can we always choose $h,h'$ in a way such that
$$\Phi_1(t,x)=h' \circ \Phi_2(t,h(x)) \quad \forall x \in M, t \in T$$

To me it is quite clear that this is always possible locally, but I am not sure if it is also possible globally.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you write _continuous functions_ do you mean specifically _homeomorphisms of $M$_, or _continuous mappings from $M$ to $M$_, or something else?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Just any continuous mapping. I especially don't mean homeomorphism. There, it is clear that it is impossible. Not all flows are topological conjugate.